# How can I have a minimal match between two known tokens?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a selection of text that looks like the following.  I need to do a rudimentary edit on it, but can't fathom the regex that I need.  Maybe it's just been a long day, and I'm not seeing what I need.

Sample data:

```
START ITEM = 1235
    BEGIN
        WORD
        RATE = 98
        MORE WORDS
        CODE = XX
        STUFF
    END
    BEGIN
        TEXT
        MORE WORDS
        RATE = 57
        ADDITIONAL TEXT
        CODE = YY
        OTHER THINGS
    END
STOP
START ITEM = 9983
    BEGIN
        WORD
        RATE = 01
        MORE WORDS
        CODE = AA
        STUFF
    END
    BEGIN
        TEXT
        MORE WORDS
        RATE = 99
        ADDITIONAL TEXT
        CODE = XX
        OTHER THINGS
    END
STOP
```

I'm given a `CODE` and an `ITEM` number, and need to edit the rate in the appropriate `BEGIN`/`END` section.  Fortunately, the sections are well-defined with `STOP`/`START` `BEGIN`/`END` (they're keywords, and aren't anywhere else).

My toolbox for this is Perl regular expressions.*

The first solution I tried didn't work (values hard-coded):

```
    $tx =~ s/(START \s ITEM \s = \s 9983.*?
                            BEGIN
                                .*?
                               RATE \s = \s )\d+
                                    (.*?       # Goes too far
                                CODE \s = \s XX)
                        /$1$newRate$2
                        /sx;
```

Because the indicated code winds up matching too much, finding the correct code farther down but always editing the first entry.

Suggestions?

---

`*` The actual code relies on the regex being added onto a stack of regexes (sort of a post-processing filter) that are each applied in turn to the text to do edits. Heck, I could do a full-on parser if I had the text. But I was hoping not to have to break that code open and stick with the API I've got.

Comment: Actually, the `.*?` is going exactly as far as it's supposed to--the problem is that it's starting too early.  But JS Bangs' (amended) solution is the cure for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regex is poorly suited for this sort of problem. I recommend a simple iterative solution:

```
while (<FILE>) {
    # push lines straight to output until we find the START that we want
    print OUT $_;
    next unless m/START ITEM = $number/;

    # save the lines until we get to the CODE that we want
    my @lines;
    while (<FILE>)
    {
        push @lines, $_;
        last if m/CODE = $code/;
    }

    # @lines now has everything from the START to the CODE. Get the last RATE in
    # @lines and change its value.
    my $strref = \( grep m/RATE/ @lines )[-1];
    $$strref = $new_value;

    # print out the lines we saved and exit the loop
    print OUT @lines;
    last;
}
```

**Edit:** If you really want a regex, you can use something like this (untested):

```
$tx =~ s/(START \s+ ITEM \s+ = \s+ 9983.*?
                            BEGIN
                                .*?
                               RATE \s+ = \s+ )\d+
                                ( (?: (?! END ) . )*
                                    CODE \s+ = \s+ XX)
                        /$1$newRate$2
                        /sx;
```

The added `(?: (?! END ) . )*` ensures that the match between RATE and CODE doesn't cross an END. But this will be massively slower than a non-regex approach.

Comment: You got to it faster than I did. +1!

Comment: I wasn't kidding when I said my toolbox had perl regexes in them.  The actual code relies on the regex being added onto a stack of regexes (sort of a callback regex) that are each applied in turn to the text.  

Heck, I could do a full-on parser if I had the text.  But I was hoping not to have to break that code open and stick with the API I've got.

Comment: Sounds like clintp has a DailyWTF entry.

Comment: @JSBangs: Speed isn't the issue, so this should work just dandy.  Thanks.

Comment: @clintp: you should put those comments in your original question.

Comment: If `ADDITIONAL TEXT` contains the phrase "DIDN'T ABEND" or something like that nothing will match. That's why I used word boundaries (and now an isolated word on a line.)

Comment: @briandfoy: comments added to question

Answer (score 4):

Although I don't like how much it backtracks, making the catchall *greedy* between `BEGIN` and `RATE` will allow you to skip to the `RATE` in the section where `CODE`=`XX`. Like this:

```
$tx = qr/(START \s+ ITEM \s+ = \s+ 9983 \s+ 
                        BEGIN
                            .*
                           RATE \s+ = \s+ )\d+
...
```

The main problem with this is that it will jump into another `ITEM` if necessary, so you have to make sure you don't gobble up `STOP`. Like so:

```
my $tx = qr/(START \s+ ITEM \s+ = \s+ 9983 \s+
                 BEGIN
                     (?: (?! \b STOP \b ) . )*
                    RATE \s+ = \s+ )\d+
                         (.*?       # Goes too far
                     CODE \s+ = \s+ XX)
          /msx
          ;
```

It still backtracks more than I'd like.

(An hour later) I realized that the `RATE` and the `CODE` field whose value is `XX` must not be divided by an `END`. Thus another solution is:

```
my $tx = qr/(START \s+ ITEM \s+ = \s+ 9983 \s+
                 BEGIN
                     .*?
                    RATE \s+ = \s+ )\d+
                         ((?:(?! ^ \s+ END \s* $ ) . )*? 
                     CODE \s+ = \s+ XX)
                        /msx
                        ;
```

( I revised this to only look for END by itself in a line. If `ADDITIONAL TEXT` could contain a single END, then it would be hard to parse no matter what)

I'm thinking this one doesn't backtrack as much, because it just starts from `RATE =` and then scans for `CODE =` before it hits `END` if we don't have `CODE = XX`, then it prunes back to the position where it thought it matched `RATE` and goes looking for the next `RATE`. We could add the negative lookahead for `STOP` if we don't know that Item #9983 is definitely going to have a code of 'XX'.

---

**Edited** to eliminate false `\s` problem.

**Note:** this now takes the following section:

```
START ITEM = 9983
    BEGIN
        WORD
        RATE = 01
        MORE WORDS
        CODE = AA
        STUFF
    END
    BEGIN
        TEXT
        MORE WORDS
        RATE = 99
        ADDITIONAL TEXT <-- DON'T END HERE!
        CODE = XX
        OTHER THINGS
    END
STOP
```

Comment: That wasn't the problem.  The \s's got lost as I was transcribing into my browser from a non-internet connected system.  Sorry.

Comment: @Axeman This greedy-with-negative-lookahead strategy is a good idea, but the specific solution fails for `1235` and `XX`. I think you can solve the problem by applying the approach more widely, using similar lookaheads for END.

Comment: @FM: Funny, I didn't read your comment before updating my expression, but your suggestion is there, now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions is not always the best answer for parsing text.  Your example shows that you really have a file that can be represented with a grammar.  It will be much simpler to use a parser to extract the fields and then do the update on the extracted information.